# Creating new users with Commerce & Rules: ERROR

Tags: commerce, rules, users

[Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) has a problem with the [Rule](http://drupal.org/project/rules) to create a new User account for an anonymous order:

```
ERROR: Missing configuration for parameter param_field_[fieldname]
```

According to [a drupalcommerce.org comment](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/2704/missing-configuration-parameter-paramfieldfirstname) this is because of fields being required:

> The rule “Create a new account for an anonymous order” will fail if any of the fields it attempts to create are required. That failure will generate the ERROR: Missing configuration for parameter param_field_.

Despite this insight, no answer is give for how to take care of the error. It is necessary to my site to require some fields upon user registration. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you tried removing the "required" attribute to your fields and checking if that removes the error?

Comment: Yes, removing the requirement removes the error. However, I need to require certain fields. I'm asking for a solution that allows fields to be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During anonymous checkout, an email address is collected from the 'Account information' pane to create a new user (or append the order to an existing user).

You should be able to hook into the form on the 'Account information' pane and add your required fields. You will probably have to modify the rule (Create a new account for an anonymous order) to send along the extra fields for creating a new user with the required fields - when marked required, custom fields added to the user are added to the Create Entity action for user as well.

You can populate these fields using existing variables, or fields added to the Commerce Order or Commerce Billing Profile, or create your own variables (eg via `hook_token_info_alter()` to make variables available through the commerce_order).

Comment: Thanks. I've got my rulesets open but I'm not sure if I should edit the built-in one or create a new one. Either way, what action(s) does this require? Do I do something to the user profile entity, or?

Comment: This saved my day. Here is the tip: "If you make a field in user account as Required, it will appear in Create Entity action for User."

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Commerce User Profile Pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_user_profile_pane) and add the required field(s) to it.